# Turning multiple rows into single row based on ID, and keeping null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have tried some of the various solutions posted on Stack for this issue but none of them keep null values (and it seems like the entire query is built off that assumption).

I have a table with 1 million rows.  There are 10 columns. The first column is the id.  Each id is unique to "item" (in my case a sales order) but has multiple rows.  Each row is either completely null or has a single value in one of the columns.  No two rows with the same ID have data for the same column.  I need to merge these multiple rows into a single row based on the ID. However, I need to keep the null values. If the first column is null in all rows I need to keep that in the final data.

Can someone please help me with this query I've been stuck on it for 2 hours now.

```
id - Age - firstname - lastname
1    13      null      null
1    null     chris    null
```

should output

```
1 13 chris null
```

Comment: `I need to keep the null values`, what does this means?, do you want to concatenate an actual `'null'` string?.

Comment: Please show your table structure, sample data, and expected output so that people don't have to guess what you want and waste time fixing posts after they find out that they guessed wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: that sounds like a lot of assumptions in data without any way to constrain it... are you saying each ID could have 10 rows, each row having a single value in one of 9 other columns never repeating a column having a value for the same ID?

Comment: share some sample data and how data looks like

Comment: just post the table and someone can help you edit it

Comment: @ChristopherMaggiulli . . . To create a table, just put four spaces at the beginning of each row.  That will format it using fixed-width fonts, so things line up nicely.

Comment: You should actually get those results using the queries from both answers

Comment: @ChristopherMaggiulli I've formatted them for you. You can select the table and press the `{}` button. Adding a line before the table with `<!-- Language: lang-none -->` will remove the coloring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some others have mentioned, you should use an aggregation query to achieve this.

```
select t1.id, max(t1.col1), max(t1.col2)
from tableone t1
group by t1.id
```

This should return nulls. If you're having issues handling your nulls, maybe implement some logic using ISNULL(). Make sure your data fields really are nulls and not empty strings.

If nulls aren't being returned, check to make sure that EVERY single row that has a particular ID has ONLY nulls. If one of them returns an empty string, then yes, it will drop the null and return anything else over the null.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want an aggregation query:

```
select id, max(col1) as col1, max(col2) as col2, . . .
from t
group by id;
```

If all values are `NULL`, then this will produce `NULL`.  If one of the rows (for an `id`) has a value, then this will produce that value.

Comment: @ChristopherMaggiulli . . . If all values are `NULL` in a column for  given id, then the result is `NULL`.  The appears to be what you are asking for:  "If the first column is null in all rows I need to keep that in the final data."

Answer (score 3):

```
select id, max(col1), max(col2).. etc
from mytable
group by id
```

Comment: @ChristopherMaggiulli you keep repeating that without explaining what do you actually mean

Comment: @ChristopherMaggiulli As I said, just post the table data and someone can edit your question so it gets formatted correctly